# How to create table and its structure using jquery for HTML

Tags: jquery, html, json, html-table

I have values coming from database in a variable by parsing it from `JSON`. Now I want to create a `HTML` table structure like below

```
<table class="table dataList fiberEngg">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="row noPadding">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 colPadding">
                        MHBHNDMUNVMBSPN006_BU
                        <a class="button"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a class="button"><i class="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 colPadding">
                        <p><strong>Request Id :</strong>053214</p>
                        <p><strong>Last Updated by :</strong>Sameer Parab</p>
                        <p><strong>Status :</strong>Partial HOTO with Partial LIT</p>
                        <p><strong>Pending Since :</strong>1 Day</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and my JSON is below

```
[
    {
        "SPAN_ID": "GJVAPIMHKAKHSPN003_BU",
        "MAINTENANCEZONECODE": "INMUMIBH01",
        "REQ_ID": 4.0,
        "LAST_UPDATE_BY": "HARDIK1.SHAH",
        "STATUS_NAME": "HOTO without LIT",
        "PENDING_DAYS": 7.0
    }
]
```

how can I create a table structure in below code

```
 success: function (response) {

    var datalist = JSON.parse(response);
    var table = $("#tblFiberEngData");
    table.empty();

    datalist.forEach(function (dataRow) {
        //here i want to create structure
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is your attempt? What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: @CBroe: I am unable to create the `HTML` structure. For ex: I am unable to append div inside td. Can you suggest how should I do

Comment: If you don’t know how to dynamically create elements, append them to other elements etc., using jQuery, then start with its documentation on the relevant methods.

Comment: @CBroe: Will do it for sure. but for now how Can i move ahead. any help from ur side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this inside your success area.

Start from my_table and below.

```
var data = [
    {
        "SPAN_ID": "GJVAPIMHKAKHSPN003_BU",
        "MAINTENANCEZONECODE": "INMUMIBH01",
        "REQ_ID": 4.0,
        "LAST_UPDATE_BY": "HARDIK1.SHAH",
        "STATUS_NAME": "HOTO without LIT",
        "PENDING_DAYS": 7.0
    },
     {
        "SPAN_ID": "WDASDF@R#&^@I",
        "MAINTENANCEZONECODE": "WKUYTEISA",
        "REQ_ID": 4.0,
        "LAST_UPDATE_BY": "TEST",
        "STATUS_NAME": "OK",
        "PENDING_DAYS": 7.0
    }
];

var datatojson = JSON.stringify(data);
var parsedata = jQuery.parseJSON(datatojson);

// start from this inside success: function (response) { bla.. bla.. 
var my_table = $(".my_table");
my_table.empty();

$.each(parsedata,function( key, val ){
    var my_tr = "<tr>"
        + "<td>"
        + "<div class='row noPadding'>"
        + "<div class='col-xs-6 colPadding'>"
        + val.SPAN_ID
        + "<a class='button'><i class='fa fa-map-marker' aria-hidden='true'></i></a><a class='button'><i class='fa fa-list' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>"
        + "</div>"
        + "<div class='col-xs-6 colPadding'>"
        + "<p><strong>Request Id :</strong>" + val.REQ_ID + "</p>"
        + "<p><strong>Last Updated by :</strong>" + val.LAST_UPDATE_BY + "</p>"
        + "<p><strong>Status :</strong>" + val.STATUS_NAME + "</p>"
        + "<p><strong>Pending Since :</strong>" + val.PENDING_DAYS + "</p>"
        + "</div>"
        + "</div>"
        + "</td>"
        + "</tr>";

    my_table.append(my_tr); 
});
```

And jsfiddle based on your code : https://jsfiddle.net/synz/kez21quf/

Comment: your code is working. but on one img click my `fa fa-list` is not working

Comment: Maybe that's because this `code(append)` run after you done set something `on(click)` for that `fa-list` before. Change it to `$(document).on('click','.fa',function(){ // do something });`. So it still can trigger its click even when you add new element

Comment: `<a class='button'><i class='fa fa-list' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>` is this want u mean not working? do you have something `on('click')` event @ you just want this button have a link to go somewhere else. Because you `<a>` doesn't have its `href=*`.

Comment: see, i have to open pop up which is inside this code `$('.fiberEngg .fa-list').on('click', function () {
 $('.fiberEnggDetails').css({ 'display': 'block' });
}` but click is not working

Comment: `$('.fiberEngg .fa-list').on('click',` change to `$(document).on('click','.fiberEngg .fa-list',`

Comment: its already define, I cant change that. can u see in html why its not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160479/discussion-between-vvvv-and-synz).

Answer (score 0):

In order to append elements dynamically using jQuery, try this:

```js
$( "td" ).append( "<div></div>" );
```